# NSInternalInconsistencyException when querying Core Data while iOS is migrating iCloud transaction logs

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I started seeing this error reported on Crashlytics after updating the model in my iOS app (lightweight migration, since the data store is synced via iCloud). The issue seems to affect ~2-3% of all sessions and I found it was very difficult to reproduce in a test environment.

---

**Here is the error (stack trace of the crashing thread):**

```
Thread : Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  webtv                          0x000000010031ad28 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4298337576
1  webtv                          0x000000010031ad28 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4298337576
2  webtv                          0x000000010031b1d8 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4298338776
3  webtv                          0x0000000100305c08 CLSHandler + 4298251272
4  webtv                          0x0000000100318f20 __CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke + 4298329888
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001994c9770 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001994d49c4 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 100
7  webtv                          0x0000000100318ab8 CLSExceptionRecord + 4298328760
8  webtv                          0x00000001003188d0 CLSExceptionRecordNSException + 4298328272
9  webtv                          0x0000000100318530 CLSTerminateHandler() + 4298327344
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x0000000198372f44 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
11 libc++abi.dylib                0x0000000198372fd0 std::set_new_handler(void (*)()) + 90
12 libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000198cdc1a4 _destroyAltHandlerList + 10
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001994c9784 _dispatch_client_callout + 36
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001994d49c4 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 100
15 CoreData                       0x0000000183e53b08 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 252
16 webtv                          0x00000001001320ec WTVCoreDataHelper.(executeSync in _B3CAA6076B08D24EA69CA58785DFF9DB)(NSFetchRequest, error : inout NSError?) -> [AnyObject]? (WTVCoreDataHelpers.swift:136)
17 webtv                          0x00000001001390f0 WTVCoreDataHelper.defaultProfile() -> WTVProfile? (WTVCoreDataHelpers.swift:529)
18 webtv                          0x00000001001335c0 WTVCoreDataHelper.(defaultProfileIfNil in _B3CAA6076B08D24EA69CA58785DFF9DB)(WTVProfile?) -> WTVProfile? (WTVCoreDataHelpers.swift:204)
19 webtv                          0x0000000100132de8 WTVCoreDataHelper.(systemFolder in _B3CAA6076B08D24EA69CA58785DFF9DB)(WTVProfile?) -> WTVFolder? (WTVCoreDataHelpers.swift:179)
20 webtv                          0x00000001001358a8 WTVCoreDataHelper.homePage(profile : WTVProfile?) -> WTVPage? (WTVCoreDataHelpers.swift:345)
21 webtv                          0x0000000100273bec SWWebBrowserViewController.homePageUrl.getter (SWWebBrowserViewController.swift:97)
22 webtv                          0x00000001002607f4 SWBrowserHomeButton.evaluateForChangeOfState(NSURL?) -> () (SWBrowserControlButtons.swift:94)
23 webtv                          0x000000010025e5b8 SWBrowserControlButton.store(FASFluxStore!, didEmitChangeNotification : NSNotification!) -> () (SWBrowserControlButtons.swift:36)
24 webtv                          0x000000010025e630 @objc SWBrowserControlButton.store(FASFluxStore!, didEmitChangeNotification : NSNotification!) -> () (SWBrowserControlButtons.swift)
[...]
49 GraphicsServices               0x000000018ef98088 GSEventRunModal + 180
50 UIKit                          0x00000001896caf60 UIApplicationMain + 204
51 webtv                          0x00000001002c0c60 main (AppDelegate.swift:19)
52 libdyld.dylib                  0x00000001994fa8b8 start + 4
```

**...and here is the iOS thread performing some iCloud transaction logs migration**

```
Thread : com.apple.coredata.ubiquity.entry.pq
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000199608c6c semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001994da684 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 244
2  Foundation                     0x00000001850fed94 -[NSFileCoordinator(NSPrivate) _blockOnAccessClaim:] + 380
3  Foundation                     0x00000001850ff8b0 -[NSFileCoordinator(NSPrivate) _coordinateReadingItemAtURL:options:error:byAccessor:] + 440
4  Foundation                     0x00000001850fd8fc -[NSFileCoordinator coordinateReadingItemAtURL:options:error:byAccessor:] + 72
5  CoreData                       0x0000000183f23280 -[PFUbiquityFileCoordinator coordinateReadingItemAtLocation:options:retryOnError:error:byAccessor:] + 140
6  CoreData                       0x0000000183f3c27c -[PFUbiquityLocation fileExistsAtLocationWithLocalPeerID:error:] + 324
7  CoreData                       0x0000000183f77790 -[PFUbiquitySafeSaveFile existsInCloud] + 88
8  CoreData                       0x0000000183f4b958 -[PFUbiquityMigrationManager migrateTransactionLogs:andBaselineIfNecessaryForStoreName:peerID:error:] + 1328
9  CoreData                       0x0000000183f5db18 -[PFUbiquitySetupAssistant initializeBaselineForStore:error:] + 2576
10 CoreData                       0x0000000183f5a3b4 -[PFUbiquitySetupAssistant finishSetupForStore:error:] + 2324
11 CoreData                       0x0000000183f59828 -[PFUbiquitySetupAssistant finishSetupWithRetry:] + 152
12 CoreData                       0x0000000183f222a8 __57-[PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntry executeBlockOnPrivateQueue:]_block_invoke + 64
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001994c97b0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001994c9770 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001994d575c _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001994cd274 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001994c9770 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001994d7bb0 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001994d734c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
20 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001996e9478 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
21 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001996e9028 start_wqthread + 4
```

---

I believe my code follows best practices for core data concurrency (see relevant extracts from the `Swift` code below). In particular

- The `managedObjectContext` is configured with the `PrivateQueueConcurrencyType`
- All calls to Core Data APIs are wrapped in a `managedObjectContext.performBlock()`
- `managedObjectContext` is saved and reset in `storeWillChange`

  What am I missing?

**Here is the code that crashes**

```
private func executeSync(request: NSFetchRequest) -> [AnyObject]? {        
    var results: [AnyObject]?
    if let moc = managedObjectContext {
      moc.performBlockAndWait({ () -> Void in
        do {
          try results = moc.executeFetchRequest(request) // Crashes here
        } catch let error as NSError {
          ERROR("ERROR executeFetchRequest of WTVCoreDataHelper threw an error \(error)")
        }
      })
    }
    return results
  }
```

**Setup of of the `persistentStoreCoordinator`, `managedObjectContext`**

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("WebVideoCast.sqlite")
    var options = [NSObject:AnyObject]()
    options[NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey] = kConstants.ubiquityStoreIdentifier
    options[NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption] = true
    options[NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption] = true
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
      try coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: options)
    } catch var error as NSError {
      coordinator = nil
      var dict = [NSObject:AnyObject]()
      dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
      dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
      dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
      error = NSError(domain: kConstants.errorDomain, code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
      ERROR("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
      abort()
    } catch {
      fatalError()
    }
    return coordinator
    }()

  lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if coordinator == nil {
      return nil
    }

    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    // Set the MergePolicy to prioritise external inputs
    let mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy(mergeType:NSMergePolicyType.MergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicyType )
    managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = mergePolicy

    return managedObjectContext
    }()
```

**Relevant delegate methods:**

```
@objc func storeWillChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
      moc.performBlockAndWait({ () -> Void in
        if moc.hasChanges {
          do {
            try moc.save()
          } catch let error as NSError {
            ERROR("ERROR Unresolved error while saving context \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
          } catch {
            fatalError()
          }
        }
        moc.reset()
      })
    }
  }
```

---

Update: I just recently reproduced the problem once on a device where the model had been updated to the latest version - so I am really not sure that the lightweight migration is a contributing factor.

Comment: I have never been able to perform a lightweight migration reliably on a Core Data store that is sync'ed via iCloud. I always create a local store and then perform the migration on the local store and then share the local store via iCloud again.  This seems 100% reliable whereas migrating the store while it's shared is hit and miss, mostly miss in my experience.

Comment: Thanks @DuncanGroenewald ...though that doesn't sound very encouraging :( In this case I am really less than sure that the problem is caused by the actual model migration because I definitely reproduced the issue at least once on a test device which had previously been upgraded to the latest version of the model. The only clue I have to describe what iOS might actually be doing is the stack trace from the `com.apple.coredata.ubiquity.entry.pq` thread (`migrateTransactionLogs ...`)